# collapse / expand of panel-heading body

Tags: javascript, jquery

The given below code used to collapse/expand. I used this code, where there were multiple panel-headings to collapse/expand. And it worked fine, but I don't know how this is working. I have taken this code from internet.
It would be helpful if someone can explain , whats going  on here or point me to somehere, where I can read about this.
second, can I use this same function without changing on a page, where ther is only one panel-heading div.Could you give an example, if yes.

```
function bindCollapseEvents(panels, numPanels) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i < panels.length ; i++) {
        var heading = $(panels[i]).children('.panel-heading');
        var bodyCollapse = $(panels[i]).children('.panel-body');
        if (heading.length != 0 && bodyCollapse.length != 0) {
            numPanels++;
            // $(heading[0]).attr('data-toggle', 'collapse');
            // Use this instead of the data-toggle attribute to let [more/less] be clicked without collapsing panel
            if ($(heading[0]).attr('class') == 'panel-heading') {
                $(heading[0]).click(toggleSingleCollapse);
            }
            $(heading[0]).attr('data-target', '#panelBodyCollapse');
            $(heading[0]).attr('id', 'panelHeading');
            $(heading[0]).css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $(bodyCollapse[0]).attr('id', 'panelBodyCollapse');
        }
    }
    return numPanels;
}




function toggleSingleCollapse(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('a') && !$(e.target).is('input')) {
        var glyphIcon = $(this).find('.glyphicon');
        var className = $(glyphIcon[0]).attr('class');
        if (className.indexOf('glyphicon-chevron-up') != -1) {
            hideSingleCollapse($(e.currentTarget).attr('data-target'));
        } else {
            showSingleCollapse($(e.currentTarget).attr('data-target'));
        }
    }
}



function showSingleCollapse(e) {
    var heading = $(e).parent().children('.panel-heading');
    var glyphIcon = $(heading[0]).find('.glyphicon');
    $(glyphIcon[0]).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $(glyphIcon[0]).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    $(e).collapse('show');
    $(heading).find('a.btn').show();
}

function hideSingleCollapse(e) {
    var heading = $(e).parent().children('.panel-heading');
    var glyphIcon = $(heading[0]).find('.glyphicon');
    $(glyphIcon[0]).removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-up');
    $(glyphIcon[0]).addClass('glyphicon-chevron-down');
    $(e).collapse('hide');
    $(heading).find('a.btn').hide();
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should start looking where you found it.

Comment: @ScottHunter there is not any documentation or explanation about it. They just give the code.

Comment: Not very well written to begin with and would require far too much explaining. You can research most of it yourself in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)

Comment: @charlietfl sure, I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main thing in the above code is switch logic, which is used to `hide/show` the respective content.

---

The only thing switch logic is doing here to add/remove respective `CSS class` on the elements which control their visibility like accordion

**Switch logic modules:** `showSingleCollapse(e)` &  `hideSingleCollapse(e)`

Beyond this there is logic for validation check like not to add same `css class` if it already has.

**My Suggestion:** There is better accordion logic out there in [jQuery Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) itself but you can refer this code to understand the real logic behind **Accordion**

[image]